# Group-Object is showing a hashtable when using calculated properties

Tags: powershell, grouping, powershell-4.0

**Background**

From list of predefined servernames, I'm searching in config files and trying to group for each server all the files where it's found. A filename can be mapped to an application.

**Problem**

The grouping part is giving me problems. It keeps returning a hashlist where I just want the filename returned.

**SSCCE**  <sub>note: grouping is on filename in the sscce but the gist of the problem is the same</sub>

This example is showing the entire line where the match is found instead of just the match

```
@("A test", "Another test") | sls -pattern "\btest\b" | group filename | select name, group
```

Trying to adjust for that, I've added a calculated property to only get the match. Unfortunately, this shows the group as a Hashlist.

```
@("A test", "Another test") | sls -pattern "\btest\b" | select filename, @{n="Server";e={$_.matches[0].Value}} | group filename | select name, group
```

**TLDR; following is what I'm currently using**

```
@(
  "server1"
  , "server2"
) | 
% {sls -path "C:\PrivateWS\sources\confdoc\applicaties\*.yml" -Pattern "\b$($_)\b"} | 
select Filename, @{n="Server";e={$_.matches[0].Value}} | 
group server | select name, group
```

and this returns something like this

```
Name    Group                                                                                                                                                                                              
----    -----                                                                                                                                                                                              
server1 {@{Filename=applicationX.yml; Server=server1}, @{Filename=applicationY.yml; Server=server1}}                                                                                 
server2 {@{Filename=applicationX.yml; Server=server2}}
```

where I would like to have it return this

```
Name    Group                                                                                                                                                                                              
----    -----                                                                                                                                                                                              
server1 {applicationX.yml, applicationY.yml}                                                                                 
server2 {applicationX.yml}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give what you want (replacement for the last line of your code):

```
group server | select name, @{name='group'; expression={$_.group | Select -ExpandProperty Filename}}
```

And to get rid of the hash/curly braces:

```
group server | select name, @{name='group'; expression={(@($_.Group | Select -ExpandProperty Filename)) -join ', '}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the `-Unique` to the select and it's doing exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is the string representation of custom objects, not hashtables. You're getting that, because `Group-Object` doesn't group just one property of the input objects, but the whole objects.

I think what you actually want is convert your list of groups to a hashtable:

```
$ht = @{}
'server1', 'server2' |
    ForEach-Object { Select-String ... } |
    Select-Object Filename, @{n="Server";e={$_.matches[0].Value}} |
    Group-Object server |
    ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Filename }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar for setting the nomenclature straight. This works too.