# How to make this If-Else work

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell script template by using my device "Integrated Webcam". There's an issue at work where a touch screen is enabling when the screen is closed with it docked.

I have been trying to create said script to make it where it won't do this when you run the script and it will decide to enable or disable the touch screen device via PowerShell.

Thus bringing me here, any suggestions?

(Pardon the notes, just documenting for myself)

```
REM Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"}

Import-module .\DeviceManagement.psd1

REM Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"} | Disable-Device
REM Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"} | Enable-Device

REM Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"}
REM ***ConfigurationFlags  : CONFIGFLAG_DISABLED ---> Disabled
REM ***ConfigurationFlags  : 0           ---> Enabled

REM Variables
$OnStatus = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.Status -eq "OK"}
$OffStatus = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.Status -eq "Error"}
$DeviceID = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.DeviceID -like "USB\VID_0C45&PID_64AD&MI_00\7&342EE79C&0&0000"}


REM Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.Status -like "Error*"}

REM Get-Device ???? 
REM **Disable Device -- Works**
if 
($DeviceID -AND $OnStatus){
Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"} | Disable-Device
REM  **Else doesn't work** **Tried elseif also**
}else{
 Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"} | Enable-Device 
}

REM **Enable device -- works ** 
if ($DeviceID -AND $OffStatus){
 Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "Integrated Webcam*"} | Enable-Device 
}
```

Comment: `OnStatus` and `DeviceID` are both arrays. They always compare to true. I suspect you only need the status of your VIDxxx device so you should change your code to only get that one. Now you are getting all entities that have a status OK and all entities that have a  status Error.

Comment: `REM` is not a valid PowerShell command and would indicate that you're actually using a batch script/the cmd.exe for this which doesn't support if/else statements and most other commands in your script. Right now you're just checking whenever both variables are not `$null`/`false`. Where `DeviceID` would be your actual device and `OnStatus` the status of every PNP device. It's unlikely that you won't have a PNP device that's no "OK". Pretty much what @LievenKeersmaekers.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers JFTR, empty arrays evaluate to `$false`, non-empty arrays to `$true`. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).

Comment: "Any Suggestions?" Yes. Don't guess at how to write PowerShell code. Start with the basics. It will be less frustrating.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Powershell is awesome except when it isn't. I still can't get my head around on how to write a decent [Group-By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668636/group-object-is-showing-a-hashtable-when-using-calculated-properties) without resorting to the community for help *(unlike Ansgar... oh the envy)*

Comment: It's not a full script file, I was just making notes as I went. REM was used to be a idea of a comment. I never ran it, I was just testing it line by line to see how I went about it. I was curious as to go about make an if-else statement towards this process.